# Differential equation with zero solution of indicial equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions, frobenius-groups

I want to solve this equation

$$
y'' + (\frac{1}{x} + 4x)y' + (5+4x^2)y = 0
$$
Where $y''$ is second derivative and so on.

This equation has singuar point at $x=0$. And this is regular singular point. So, I used Frobenius method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method. When I find indicial (or characteristic) equation of the solution,
$$
p(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} x \bigg (\frac{1}{x} + 4x \bigg) = 1 \\
q(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \bigg (5+4x^2\bigg) = 0 \\
$$
Indicial equation $r(r-1) + p(0)r + q(0)=0$ becomes $ r^2=0 \implies r=0,0$.

Now, how to proceed with this equation? Any ideas, much appreciated.

Comment: your solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: You are right, the ODE has form of Bessel function. But to solve a generalized Bessel equation of $P$th order, I need roots indicial equation to determine $P$ .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this could help you but if you start setting $$y=e^{-x^2}z$$ the differential equation $$y'' + (\frac{1}{x} + 4x)y' + (5+4x^2)y = 0$$ reduces to $$x z''+z'+x z=0$$ which probably much easier to handle (it effectively corresponds to Bessel differential  equation).